# Roots of unity product

Tags: products, roots-of-unity

For each $n \in \mathbb N, n \geq 3$ calculate the product of all the n roots of unity.

Or to say it in a more stric way:

$$\prod_{w \in G_n^*}w$$

Being $G_n^*$ the primitive roots of the unity.

Comment: [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $w$ is a root of unity, so is $\frac{1}{w}$.

So, as long as $w \neq \frac{1}{w}$ they can be used to cancel each other. The only thing what you need to worry about is:

What if $w=\frac{1}{w}$ for some $w$? Those roots are left by themselves. Note that $w=\frac{1}{w}$ has 2 roots, one doesn't matter and the other is a root of unity only for certain n's.

Comment: so, one of those roots is $1$ and the other $-1$. Now can be that $-1$ is only primitive for $n = 2$, so in my case ($n\geq3$ it will never appear, and for all the $n$s the answer is 1. Is this correct?

Comment: @FranckN Almost perfect or perfect depending on the problem, which is unclear. Do you need the product of all roots, or just the primitive ones? $-1$ is a root of unity if and only if $n$ is even. You are right, it is primitive only for $n=2$ .. So if it is the product of primitive, your solution is right, if it is all, you have to account for $-1$.